# tomcat exception

Tags: java, tomcat

I recently deployed a war file.

I got the following **error**:

> [http-8080-Processor24] ERROR Exception sending context initialized
>   event o listener instance of class app.util.ApplicationEventsListener
>   [at org.apache.
>   atalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3768)]
>   ava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject
>          at app.util.ApplicationEventsListener.contextInitialized(ApplicationEven
>   sListener.java:31)
>          at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContex
>   .java:3764)
>          at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4
>   16)
>          at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:
>   173)
>          at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServl
>   t.java:549)
>          at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doGet(HTMLManagerServl
>   t.java:105)
>          at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:627)
>          at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>          at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
>   cationFilterChain.java:269)
>          at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
>   lterChain.java:188)
>          at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperV
>   lve.java:213)
>          at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextV
>   lve.java:172)
>          at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(Authentica
>   orBase.java:525)
>          at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.j
>   va:127)
>          at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.j
>   va:117)
>          at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineVal
>   e.java:108)
>          at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.jav
>   :174)
>          at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java
>   875)
>          at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.p
>   ocessConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
>          at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpo
>   nt.java:528)
>          at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFol
>   owerWorkerThread.java:81)
>          at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadP
>   ol.java:689)
>          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) aused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject
>          at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoa
>   er.java:1386)
>          at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoa
>   er.java:1232)
>          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
>          ... 23 more un 23, 2009 2:19:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start EVERE: Error
>   listenerStart un 23, 2009 2:19:46 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start EVERE: Context
>   [/omb-itbrs-web-1.5.3] startup failed due to previous errors

If anyone can help it would be great.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is the cause:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject
```

You're missing a JAR that contains the org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject.class file.

Download it from one of [these sites](http://www.whatjar.co.uk/whatjar/welcome.htm) and put it in the server /lib directory for your Tomcat installation.

What version of Tomcat are you using?  Which JDK version?

Comment: May want to be wary about what you put in the tomcat lib directory, since it makes the .jars available to any webapp.  Sticking it in the WEB-INF/lib folder in the webapp should also work.

Comment: Is class app.util.ApplicationEventsListener your class?  If so, I agree with jimr.  Could it be that your class is using XML beans?